# How can I archive documents in a Sharepoint library after a certain number of days to another SharePoint library?

Tags: 2010, library

We've tried the retention settings in the Information management policy settings, but can't seem to get it to work at all. Is there some other way to invoke archiving to another library? Or a workflow that can be created in SharePoint designer?

Any help is greatly appricated!

Comment: Can you tell us what part is not working in Retention Policy? Where is it stuck, are there any errors in log?

Comment: I guess that requires building a custom timer Job.

Comment: We get an error that the documents have been sealed when we try to add a retention stage to the whole folder. Then if we try with just a document we get an error in the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

did you opte for custom Timer Job solution? This will be executed each day number and do your job. If everything configured well there should not be issue with rights and polices cause it is worker proces who executes the job.

To see how to create timer job se [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Custom-416cd3a1)

[This](http://www.andrewconnell.com/Creating-Custom-SharePoint-Timer-Jobs) one can helps you too

Hope it will help,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

IRM should do the job. You'll first want to create a workflow that moves the file from library A to library B then deletes the item in library A. In your IRM settings, you create an expiration rule based on the date parameters you want, then tell it to start the workflow you created. This will move the item to the desired location and delete it from the library.